# Equivalent of 'stag' for vertical splits?

Tags: vim

The 'stag' command opens a tag in a new horizontal split.

Is there an equivalent command to open the tag in a new vertical split?

Answer (score 1):

`vert stag` will open the tag in a new vertical split.  `See help :vertical`.